# How to display complete details of measure in Multi KPI dimenstion in Qliksense

Tags: qliksense

I am new to Qliksense and working on a dashboard creation which will have a multi KPI dashboard with some statistics(count). My requirement is when I click on the header(category) of a dimension, instead of just the count I would like see completed details associated to each of Id.
[image]

In the screenshot attached, If I click on any category of Implementation status, I would like see all the details associated ,for ex. If I click on "Idea proved / Implemented" along with the count "21" I would like to see the details of all 21 ideas.

Can someone help me on how to approach this.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Please share solution if you did.

Comment: yes, I have posted my answer, please refer it

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it in a different way, I created a new sheet and populated all data using table under charts, added all columns and in main sheet I have updated "Total Ideas" KPI - selected "Link to sheet" option under appearance section and selected the the new sheet created with completed details.

[image]